# django-mptt serialization return children nodes outside of parent node also

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

I am using django-mptt with django-rest-framework and for recursive serialization I am using djangorestframework-recursive package but it
returns child node outside of parent node also.
I have tried to_representation() also that leads to 
same result.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField
from .models import Category

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category  
      fields = ('id','name','parent', 'children')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import CategorySerializer
from .models import Category

class CategoryListAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

Output is

```
[   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Rock",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Corase Rock",
                "parent": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Hard Rock",
                "parent": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Soft Rock",
                "parent": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Corase Rock",
        "parent": 1,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Hard Rock",
        "parent": 1,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Soft Rock",
        "parent": 1,
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Comment: How are you calling this? and can you add your viewset code as well?

Comment: I am calling by api url and I have added views.py file @KimStacks

Comment: Are you trying to fetch 1 category and all its descendants? So your call is something like `/categories/1`?

Comment: I was doing mistake in views.py instead of Category.objects.all() should be Category.objects.root_nodes()

Comment: I think it will be better if you include the expected output in the question as well. Especially since you have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem if anybody going through this I am answering here.
There is an error in views.py file queryset should be:

```
queryset = Category.objects.root_nodes()
```